# Proof $(P \land S) \rightarrow \lnot q$ in hilbert system

Tags: logic

How can I proof $(P \land S) \rightarrow \lnot q$ using this principles :

1. $p \rightarrow (q \lor r) $
2. $q \rightarrow \lnot r $
3. $r \leftrightarrow s  $

in Hilbert system and modus ponens?

Comment: $(p\land s) \to s \to r \to \lnot q$.

Comment: would you please explain which axiom of Hilbert system did you use in each step?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need principle 1, just start with the following propositional tautology:

$\fbox{4}$ $(q \rightarrow \lnot~r)$ $\rightarrow$ $((r \leftrightarrow s)$ $\rightarrow$ $((p \land s) \rightarrow \lnot~q))$ $\color{gray}{(propositional~tautology)}$

$\fbox{5}$ $(r \leftrightarrow s)$ $\rightarrow$ $((p \land s) \rightarrow \lnot~q)$ $\color{gray}{(from~2,4~by~modus~ponens)}$

$\fbox{6}$ $(p \land s) \rightarrow \lnot~q$ $\color{gray}{(from~3,5~by~modus~ponens)}$

Answer (score -1):

Axiom 2 is (q→¬r).  Substituting q with (P $\land$ S) yields 4

4 [(P $\land$ S)→¬r].

Substituting  r with q in 4 yields 5

5 [(P $\land$ S)→¬$\lnot$q].

Comment: I think $p,q,r,s$ are names, not metavariables. (How about substituting $q$ for $r$ in 2?)

Comment: @Lord_Farin  I treated the letters like object language variables.  Substituting r with q in 2 yields (q→¬q).  We don't know the intended semantics (if there does exist an intended semantics).  It could come as a Hilbert system for a 1-valued logic for all we know, in which case the above axioms do qualify as sound, and thus (q→¬q) qualifies as a tautology and a theorem.

Comment: Really? In this reading, the third axiom declares everything equivalent. That's not useful whatsoever.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Yes, really.  And yes that implies all *propositions* equivalent in such a reading.  So what?  That does come as *useful* for studying 1-valued logic.

Comment: Perhaps. But not as an answer to this question.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Wait... actually, the third axiom just says (r↔s).  We don't really know what "↔" means other than what the axiom says before we've deduced anything.  We do NOT know that the third axiom declares everything equivalent in a one-valued interpretation, we only have that if we interpret "↔" as meaning logical equivalence, and as it stands we don't know that "↔" would come as the intended symbol for logical equivalence for this system.